# Данные через TCP socket от клиента обрабатываются только один раз при подключении

Tags: c++, python, сокет, arduino

Есть python-сервер, который должен обрабатывать соединения от устройства на ESP32 и обрабатывать данные, приходящие от него (запись в БД). Устройство должно проверять наличие соединения, и в случае неудачи отправки или отсутствия подключения сохранить неотправленные данные в буфере для отложенной отправки, а также должно пытаться восстановить подключение. Однако сообщения от устройства обрабатываются один раз, при дальнейшей отправке сообщения игнорируются.

Код python-сервера:

```py
import asyncio

async def handle_echo(reader, writer):
    while True:
        try:
            data = await reader.read(100)
            message = data.decode()
            addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')
            print("Received %r from %r" % (message, addr))

            print("Send: %r" % message)
            writer.write("OK")
            await writer.drain()
        except Exception:
            break

    # print("Close the client socket")
    # writer.close()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = asyncio.start_server(handle_echo, '0.0.0.0', 8090, loop=loop)
server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

# Serve requests until Ctrl+C is pressed
print('Serving on {}'.format(server.sockets[0].getsockname()))
try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

# Close the server
server.close()
loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
loop.close()
```

Задача восстановления соединения:

```
void connKeep(void * parameter) {
  char chipidBuffer[14];
  uint64_t chipid;
  while(1) {
    if (!client.connected()) {

      if(!client.connect(server_addr, 8090)) {
        Serial.println("Connection failed");
      }
      else {
        Serial.println("Connection established!");

        chipid=ESP.getEfuseMac();//The chip ID is essentially its MAC address(length: 6 bytes).
        sprintf(chipidBuffer, "%04X%08X", (uint16_t)(chipid>>32), (uint32_t)chipid);
        String chipidStr = String(chipidBuffer);
        client.printf("{\"dev\":\"%s\"}", chipidBuffer);
      }
    }
    while (client.available()) Serial.write(client.read());
    delay(500);
    //mqtt.loop();
  }
  vTaskDelete(NULL);
}
```

Задача отправки на сервер:

```
void sendDataToDBTask(void * parameter) {
  statusRow rec;
  boolean sendStatus;
  fileQueueKeep fileKeep;
  while(1) {

    while(uxQueueMessagesWaiting(statusQueue)>=1) {
      Serial.print("Tasks in queue: ");
      Serial.println(uxQueueMessagesWaiting(statusQueue));
      xQueueReceive(statusQueue, &(rec), portMAX_DELAY);
      if (!inet) enqueueProduct(rec);
      else {

        String send = "{\"ts\":"+String(rec.ts)+"}";
        if (client.println(send) < 0) {
          Serial.println("Error sending data!");
          client.stop();
        }

      }
      xSemaphoreTake(xStorageMutex, portMAX_DELAY);
      String logString = String(rec.ts)+";"+String(rec.status)+";"+(sendStatus ? "true" : "false")+"\r\n";
      appendFile(SD, "/log.csv", logString.c_str());
      xSemaphoreGive(xStorageMutex);
    }


  }
  vTaskDelete(senderTask);
}
```

Comment: Так а в чем проблема то?

Пример не является программой, которую можно скомпилировать и отладить за вас, а по исходникам не очень понятно, что идёт не так. Где данные то отправляются? Я вот вижу client.println(send), но из вопроса не ясно - вы видите для пяти сообщений которые должны отправиться 4 сообщения Error sending data! или ни одного?

Comment: Дело в том, что не вижу ошибки, но вижу только сообщение, отправленное при подключении из задачи восстановления соединения, а из задачи отправки сообщений не приходят, даже если все хорошо